# How do I check who a public PGP/RSA key belongs to?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, rsa, key-server

I am new to public key cryptography. I see from keyservers it's possible to do a look up for public keys associated with an email address.

Is there a reverse function available to check what email/domain a public key relates to. I have several of these that need querying.

Comment: Pretty sure that there is no service that has this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the key owner provided his or her actual email adress when generating the keys you can read it from the public key.

For an asc keyfile you could simply use

```
gpg [file]
```

It should also be displayed when importing the key into Gpg4Win.

[Source](http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Analysing_PGP_Identities)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. What is the default gpg command being run here?

Comment: Another question - if I ran my own open keyserver would I be able to query and collect such data on each public key?

Comment: Also separate but related question - is there a similar method for getting any id used at generation time for SSH public keys?

Comment: @user1561108: see [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg) under heading Commands the second paragraph. If you run an open keyserver you'll get the same data that you can get from existing open keyservers, but not all PGP keys are on open keyservers or even any keyservers. SSH is a different question and stackexchange is designed to answer one question per question, plus different implementations of SSH differ and on some implementations different options or cases differ.